# R : Do not understanding the objective of a code

Tags: r

Given the following setup:

```
area.factor <- cut(state.x77[,"Area"],
                   breaks=quantile(state.x77[,"Area"],c(0,.25,.75,1)),
                   labels=c("small","medium","large"),
                   include.lowest=TRUE)

state <- data.frame(pop=state.x77[,"Population"],
                inc=state.x77[,"Income"],
                area=area.factor,
                region=state.region)

pop.area.region <- with(state,ftable(pop,area,region))
```

The following two lines of code are show the same result:

```
head(ftable(prop.table(pop.area.region,margin=2)))

head(prop.table(pop.area.region,margin=2))
```

I don't understand what effect adding `ftable` has, if any, in:

```
head(ftable(prop.table(pop.area.region,margin=2)))
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? Is there a part of the code you do not understand? Do you want to know how it works, what it produces or why it is implemented the way it is?

Comment: I think tree is asking what effect does including ftable have on prop.table(pop.area.region,margin=2).

Comment: @Backlin & Mark Miller Both you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `ftable` witll try to coerce the pop.area.region to a `ftable class`. Here 
No need to add `ftable` since pop.area.region is already an ftable.

```
identical(ftable(prop.table(pop.area.region,margin=2)),
                 prop.table(pop.area.region,margin=2))
TRUE
```